# Dialog fragment draws with a delay after screen rotate

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, screen-rotation, dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment,say A that launches another DialogFragment,say B using the FragmentManager. When I rotate the screen, sometimes the B hides behind A. Now with this situation, I can't see B and if I dismiss A, B will result in a crash. This does not happen always. I have been able to reproduce it couple of time.

---

Questions:

1. Why this might be happening?
2. Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

### Why?

---

When the screen is rotated, the activity recreates, but the `DialogFragment`'s instance was not saved, so when you call `dismiss();` on it, you get a `NullPointerException` because you called `dismiss();` on a null object.

### How to avoid

---

When you call `dismiss()`, use the **TAG* you used when you called `show(getSupportFragmentManager, TAG);` do a `findFragmentByTag(TAG);` and finally if it is shown, then call `dismiss();`.

This is what I think from the information you gave...